# Add/Change default images in Sparx EA HTML report

Tags: html, css, enterprise-architect

I'm new to Sparx EA (Currently running 14.2 and 15.2), and really like the HTML report, which we host on SharePoint to serve to customers.  However, AFTER running the HTML report, I go into the created html folder and make modifications to files, which include: Modifying the index.html to replace the ea.png file to display two logos; one on the left AND one on the right, Modify the ea.css file to modify the iframe sizes to accommodate the larger sizes of my two logos. I also change the header background image to an image that completely fills the header iframe.

This serves us just fine, but does require and handful of manual changes to the html before posting.

I've only just discovered the ability to select a manually created "style" templates!  However, I'm unable to resolve a couple issues that I would like to be able to resolve without manually manipulating the html after creation.

How can I include referenced images, either from the file system OR the image library?
For example:  in the Page-Index template, the image source is #HEADER_IMAGE#, this (of course) is resolved from the "Header Image:" prompt in the "Publish as HTML.  However, if I would like to use  a logo that is in my image library, can I overwrite the "#HEADER_IMAGE# with something to the effect of "#IMAGES#/myLogo.png"?  And to also have that logo file included in the images folder of the generated HTML report?  Ideally, as I have two logos, one automatically works by the "#HEADER_IMAGE# then other by "images/Logo2.png"  is there a way to define a "#HEADER_IMAGE_2#" that would allow me to reference that second logo, and work like the original "#HEADER_IMAGE#"

I would also like to change the CSS-MAIN .IndexHeader background-image: url(../images.hgb.gif) again, to an image I have in either a file on my file system or one from my image library in Sparx.

In my testing of this, I'm able to make the references as "images/logo1" , etc.  but then I have to manually move the file into the images folder as sparx does not do so (though it does a great job on doing so with the #HEADER_IMAGE#)!

Appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No.  After I run the HTML report, I have several "steps" to manually move image files and modify the html report to produce our pnline customer facing product.